# SET FORIENG KEY CHECKS NOT working Laravel Migration

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Even after declaring SET FOREIGN KEYS CHECKS i am unable to change type of my id column to integer. I am receiving error

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
>   SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1025 Error on rename of
>   './abc/#sql-45d_6d' to './abc/oauth_clients' (errno:
>   150) (SQL: ALTER TABLE o     auth_clients CHANGE id id int(10)
>   AUTO_INCREMENT)

```
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class AddAppIdToOauthClients extends Migration {

        /**
         * Run the migrations.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function up()
        {
                /**
                Schema::table('oauth_clients', function(Blueprint $table)
                {
                    $table->string('app_id',100);
                });
                */


                DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;');
                DB::statement('ALTER TABLE oauth_clients CHANGE id id int(10) AUTO_INCREMENT');

                DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;');
        }

        /**
         * Reverse the migrations.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function down()
        {
                /**
                Schema::table('oauth_clients', function(Blueprint $table)
                {
                    $table->dropColumn('app_id');
                });
                */

                DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;');
                DB::statement('ALTER TABLE oauth_clients CHANGE id id varchat(55);');
                DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;');

        }
                                                                                                                                        1,1           Top
```

**UPDATED:**
Here is the error showing on my INNODB STATUS

> ------------------------ LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR
>   ------------------------ 151217 17:37:37 Error in foreign key constraint of table abc/oauth_client_endpoints: there is no index in
>   referenced table which would contain the columns as the first columns,
>   or the data types in the referenced table do not match the ones in
>   table. Constraint: ,   CONSTRAINT
>   "oauth_client_endpoints_client_id_foreign" FOREIGN KEY ("client_id")
>   REFERENCES "oauth_clients" ("id") ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
>   The index in the foreign key in table is
>   "oauth_client_endpoints_client_id_redirect_uri_unique" See
>   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html
>   for correct foreign key definition.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL syntax is wrong. If you want to modify the type you need to use:

```
ALTER TABLE oauth_clients MODIFY COLUMN id INT(10) AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

[Take a look at the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html)

Comment: I tried this also. Doesn't work either. Same error returning

Comment: How can it return the same error if it isn't the same code? I just tried it in my local Laravel instance and it's working without problems.

Comment: This is related to keys that i am sure. Let me show you INNODB STATUS

Comment: That wasn't part of your original question.I think you should correct your foreign key definitions.